# CNNモデルの訓練に使用するデータの水増し手法について

Tags: python, 深層学習

2値分類をクラス分類問題として解くモデルに使用するデータの水増しの手法についての手法について質問です。

ノイズを乗せる、回転処理を加える、といった方法は思いついたのですが、どちらがCNNモデルとって有用でしょうか？

また、もしこの手法のほうが優秀だよ！など有りましたら、是非とも御教授いただけるとうれしいです。

【追記】
データは全て画像データです

Comment: これは難しい問題の1つだと思っています。回転処理という言葉が出てくるということは、質問者さんが対象にしているのは画像データでしょうか？　一般の学習について答えるにはご質問の範囲が広すぎるので、どのような学習タスクを行おうとしているのか質問文に追記して問題をより具体的にして頂けると、回答が集まりやすくなるだろうと思いました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[こんな感じ](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%20%E6%B0%B4%E5%A2%97%E3%81%97&form=EDGEAR&qs=PF&cvid=9922534028374ec7b7f7b7f200228813&cc=JP&setlang=ja-JP&PC=NMTS)で。「どちらが」ではなく、「どちらも」やってください。

必要なことは、実際に使う現場に行って、実際の画像を見ることです。私のケースでは、現場の環境光による影響が大きく、覆いをしてできるだけ影響を取り除きました。